# How to use a variable in a namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to dig up my long-lost PHP skills and have therefore stumbled on a problem. I have a function that initializes (not sure if it's a correct word for it) a class in the following fashion:

```
$foo = new \Master\Slave\$bar();
```

$bar is a defined class, obviously. But the entire thing doesn't work. This only seems to work when I do the following:

```
$foo = new $bar();
```

But with my first example, it outputs the following error:

```
unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING
```

Which means that I have to manually enter the class name, correct? But, what if I'm a stubborn nerd who doesn't want to and doesn't see the efficiency in it? Hence my question; how to pull this off without getting a bloody error?

UPDATE: Got the thing working with wrapping the \Master\Slave\$bar in a $variable. Not sure if it's the correct way of doing this, but it works and props go to [Visual Idiot](http://visualidiot.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables never bound to any namespace they will be always in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the namespacing does not work the way you are trying to.

This is how you should do it

```
namespace Master\Slave;
$bar = "theclassname";
class $bar() {
}
```

[Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nested.php)